# array of structures for 1M elements in C

Tags: c

I have the code bellow that is working the way I intended to work for a data relatively small say 10000 lines from a text file. I need it to work for a file with 1M lines. It gives seg fault and I don't know how to go around it. Can you help me?

This is called in main:

```
playersInfo player[size];
```

.......more code here

then for this part of program I have this code: (it reads a file and puts the info in the array then calculates the mvp of a player and prints the player with the highest mvp)

```
if(choice == 'D')
{
    printf("\n");
    while(i < size && fscanf(myFile, "%d %s %f %f %f %f %f %d %d %d \n", &player[i].id, player[i].name,
                    &player[i].ppg, &player[i].apg, &player[i].rpg, &player[i].spg, &player[i].mpg,
                    &player[i].vote1, &player[i].vote2, &player[i].vote3) != EOF)
    {
        player[i].mvp = 0;
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int current = i;
        if(player[current].vote1 != player[current].id)
        {
            i = findIndex(player, size, player[current].vote1);
            player[i].mvp += 3;
        }

        if((player[current].vote2 != player[current].id) && (player[current].vote2 != player[current].vote1))
        {
            i = findIndex(player, size, player[current].vote2);
            player[i].mvp += 2;
        }
        if((player[current].vote3 != player[current].id) && (player[current].vote3 != player[current].vote1) && (player[current].vote3 != player[current].vote2))
        {
            i = findIndex(player, size, player[current].vote3);
            player[i].mvp += 1;
        }
        i = current;
    }

    qsort((void *) &player, size, sizeof(playersInfo), (compfn)comparePlayersByMVP);
    printf("The MVP is %s (%d), with %d point(s).\n", player[0].name, player[0].id, player[0].mvp);
}
```

Comment: You mean `size` is 1 million?

Comment: Related: rather than testing for EOF, how about testing that the correct number of items were actually parsed in that `fscanf` call. (in this case 10)?

Comment: Shouldn't the first param to qsort just be `player`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, it should. And the cast should not be needed on the comparator function if it is declared and implemented correctly. Post that (your comment) as an answer and i'll uptick it.

Comment: @WhozCraig But OP says it works for smaller inputs. Confusing.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it works regardless because `&player` and `player` land on the same address. Its a type thing. the latter reduces to `player*`, the former a `playersInfo (*)[size]`.  That it is 1-million is clearly a blowout of the automatic variable space (only the third one I've seen today), so Shas is right and up ticked accordingly. its a purist thing to me. you're correct that it isn't "right", but it also isn't *the* problem. It **will** be a problem if left as-is and the OP takes on the pointer mantra for dynamic allocation. If that happens, he *must* pass `player`.

Comment: I'm guessing cast is there because func dec is `int comparePlayersByMvp(player*, player*);`

Comment: where do I call free(player)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. Totally forgot `player` and `&player` are same. Probably because I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: @user3386335 right before `main()` exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you are declaring your array in stack, then it may be too large for that. Consider using the heap.

```
playersInfo *player = (playersInfo*) malloc(size * sizeof(playersInfo));
```

Comment: typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*);

Comment: int comparePlayersByMVP(playersInfo *p1, playersInfo *p2)
{
   if(p1->mvp < p2->mvp)
      return 1;
   else if(p1->mvp > p2->mvp)
      return -1;
   else
      return 0;
}

Comment: a pointer and the override for comparator, it worked fine for size = 10,000

Comment: Also note that, type casting from malloc is not necessary, as the void pointer to pointer of object conversion is implicit.

Comment: the free(player) will be last line in code correct? or do I have to free(&player[i])

Comment: if the OP does this, remember to change the first parameter to `qsort()` to be `player`, not `&player`.

Comment: I took care of this and still works now for 10,000 but for 1,000,000 now it freezes... how to I free player inside this code?